# DIV Auto scrolling

Tags: php, css

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mdl_course c');

foreach($sql as $ss)
{
   $coursename = $ss->id;
   $summary = $ss->summary;
   echo '<div style="min-height:300px;">
            <div style="min-height:100px,overflow:auto;overflow-y:scroll;">'.$summary.'
            </div>
         </div>';  

}
```

Since I have more information in summary field from database and that too in html format, The summary displays out of the min-height.
I want the summary to be displayed within that height of div and overflow if it has more summary. Could anyone help me
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `height` as opposed to `min-height`, since if the height is more than 100px, it will just get larger, rather than scroll

So using `height` ... if the height came to 150px, you'll be able to scroll 50px down (if you see what I mean).